# Are password policies accessible by Apex classes?

Tags: apex

Are password policies in my salesforce organisation accessible by Apex classes ? I would like to use them for custom VF pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean things like:

- User passwords expire in
- Enforce password history
- Minimum password length
- ...

presented in the "Password Policies" page of Setup then I think the answer is you cannot. The information is not exposed to SOQL and I know of no API that returns this information.

Comment: Thnaks for queck reply
So is there no way to get the password policies by using apex code?

Comment: AFAIK no. The answer here was no too https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000094PBIAY.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [fflib Metadata API wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/tree/master/apex-mdapi) to change Password Policies via apex.